# SQL percentage syntax

Tags: sql

May I ask why I should use `CodeA` instead of `CodeB` for calculating the percentage? The result are totally different.

Thank you so much for your help!

---

**CodeA**:

```
select name, round(sum(amount_paid) /
  (select sum(amount_paid) from order_items) * 100.0, 2) as pct
from order_items
group by 1
order by 2 desc;
```

---

**CodeB**:

```
select name, round((amount_paid /
  sum(amount_paid)) * 100.0, 2) as pct
from order_items
group by 1
order by 2 desc;
```

---

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (Those queries are product specific.)

Comment: I am following the tutorial in Codecademy. So I guess is Periscope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*CodeB* is totally wrong because it uses wrong `GROUP BY` statement (`amount_paid` column without aggregate function).

Strict databases will trowing error if you try to use this query.

*CodeA* uses subselect `(select sum(amount_paid) from order_items)` which calculates total `sum(amount_paid)` from table and then uses it for calculating percentage for each row.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to be sure without knowing the database and the data you are operating on. I believe however that the group by section in SQL is executed before the select section. This means that in CodeB I think the records have already been grouped by the Name column by the time sum(amount_paid) is executed on the amount_paid field. This means it would be calculating the sum of the records by group instead of all the records.